# How to link C libraries in makefile

Tags: c, makefile, sqlite

I am working on an already existing C code and now I have created a database using sqlite in C. The program works well. But now I need to create a makefile for that. I compiled the program using

```
gcc cliDemo.c -l sqlite3
```

But now since I am using a makefile, I need to put this in the makefile. I have tried several things but nothing worked.

```
EXEC      = telescope 
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -fno-strict-aliasing -g -I/usr/include/libxml2  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H
LDFLAGS = -lxml2 -lpthread -lm -lz


AR = @AR@
ARFLAGS = @ARFLAGS@
RANLIB = @RANLIB@

INSTALL_MODE= -m 0755

# Include some boilerplate Gnu makefile definitions.
prefix = /usr/local

exec_prefix = ${prefix}
bindir = ${exec_prefix}/bin
libdir = ${exec_prefix}/lib
infodir = ${prefix}/share/info
includedir = ${prefix}/include
datadir = ${prefix}/share
docdir = $(datadir)/doc/telescope
localedir = $(datadir)/locale

mandir = ${prefix}/share/man
manpfx = man
man1ext = .1
man1dir = $(mandir)/$(manpfx)1man3ext = .3man3dir = $(mandir)/$(manpfx)3

htmldir = ${docdir}

SRCDIR = ./src
BINDIR = ./bin
OBJECTDIR = ./Obj
MAINOBJS  = $(OBJECTDIR)/telescope.o
MAINEXEC  = $(BINDIR)/telescope

OBJECTS1 = $(MAINOBJS)

all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS1) 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS1) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(MAINEXEC)

$(OBJECTDIR)/telescope.o: $(SRCDIR)/telescope.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRCDIR)/telescope.c -o $(OBJECTDIR)/telescope.o 


clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(MAINEXEC) $(OBJECTS1)   


# build tests
build-tests: .build-tests-post

.build-tests-pre:
# Add your pre 'build-tests' code here...

.build-tests-post: .build-tests-impl
# Add your post 'build-tests' code here...

# run tests
test: .test-post

.test-pre:
# Add your pre 'test' code here...

.test-post: .test-impl
# Add your post 'test' code here...
```

This is the code present in makefile. I am not understanding how to link the sqlite3 here.

Comment: Doesn't work if you add `-lsqlite3` at the end of `LDFLAGS`?

Comment: "I have tried several things but nothing worked.". What exactly did you try? If you don't tell us how can we tell you what you may have done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you are linking against dynamic (*.so) library you should change the original make file. In particular, you should change the `LDFLAGS` line to look like this:

```
LDFLAGS = -lxml2 -lpthread -lm -lz -lsqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to use that Makefile as a template. It's a bit oversized for this simple command, but if you want to do it:

The line in question is

```
LDFLAGS = ...
```

Add your `-lsqlite3` behind `-lz`. If you really want to build just your cliDemo, then you'd like to remove all other stuff behind `CFLAGS =` and `LDFLAGS =`, because these variables are used to build your command line.

Replace `telescope` with `cliDemo` everywhere and put your cliDemo.c into the `src` directory.

Additionally, I think that the Makefile rule

```
$(OBJECTDIR)/telescope.o: $(SRCDIR)/telescope.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $(SRCDIR)/telescope.c -o $(OBJECTDIR)/telescope.o
```

should be replaced with a generic rule:

```
$(OBJECTDIR)/%.o: $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Which means "you can build any file of the pattern `obj/*.o` from `obj/*.c` by executing the line below. $(CC) and $(CFLAGS) are replaced with the content defined above. $< is replaced with the file name right hand of the colon, $@ is replaced with the file name left hand of it. Make sure the second line is indented with a real tab and not spaces.

Allow me to give you an advice: Probably it's best you read a Makefile tutorial to understand the logic. It's hard to debug a Makefile anyway, but nearly impossible if one is not aware that it is not a description of a procedure, but a definition of a set of rules.